# shadow of 3d objects in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, 3d

How to create shadow of 3d object in javafx?
I tried to create with

```
Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ball.fxml"));

Shadow shadow = new Shadow();

root2.setEffect(shadow);
```

Here the results :

[Without shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dfr6J.png)

[With shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGBB1.png)

Can someone help me to create shadows of 3d objects?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Shadow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/effect/Shadow.html) effect in JavaFX is for implementing [drop shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop_shadow) style effects for 2D objects; it will not create appropriate shadow effects for 3D objects and is not built for that purpose.

The core JavaFX 8 3D API has no in-built methods for supporting generation of shadow effects for 3D objects.

You could read up on [various techniques for implementing shadows for 3D objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_mapping) and attempt implementing an appropriate algorithm based on the graphics primitives that are supplied with the Java 8 3D API.  Doing so would likely be a pretty difficult task IMO.

If shadows for 3D objects are important for you, you may wish to consider an alternative [3D API that provides a greater degree of 3D shadow support](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=lwjgl%20shdows&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=lwjgl%20shadows).