# JAVA FX 3D Light

Tags: javafx-8, javafx-3d

Hi I'm trying to make the sun moon and earth. I came out and they are moving around each other in 3 planes. I have problems with light. When the moon comes to the ground, it does not darken and when the moon is between the sun and the earth, it does not drop the shadow to the ground. I use *JAVA FX 3D PointLight*

Comment: It's possible that you have ambient lights set for your objects or that your pointlight just isn't powerful enough to cause a shadow.  Without a code sample its impossible to debug.
Post a working code sample and we can investigate.

Comment: Well, I'll outline my code in the evening - when I put a black and white light between the earth and the moon on the planet of dullness, then the destitute does not happen - the white light that is placed before the ground is something overwhelming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no one has stated the absence of 3d shadows in javaFX 3d because it has never been present, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36701243/8556269) might be useful to your case

> The core JavaFX 8 3D API has no in-built methods for supporting generation of shadow effects for 3D objects.

Comment: Quite right!
to create a shadow for 3D objects you need to apply math and current api - unfortunately I did not have time to deal with it further

Answer (score 0):

It was previously reported that javafx does not support shadows

Comment: Hi, where was this reported and by whom? Please edit your answer to be more specific - including sources, documentations, etc. to prevent more questions from the asker.

Comment: It was reported as the answer to other questions on this site (like this 
one httpss://stackoverflow.com/questions/36696261/shadow-of-3d-objects-in-javafx) . If I'm wrong, tell me please how to use the shadows. By the way, normal pointlight does not drop any shades (while selfiluminate is set to null and the light is not ambient) and the shadow class is for 2d elements only